# CSS Transform & Transition which prefixes (e.g. -o-) are necessary?

Tags: css

Is there any up to date documentation that lists which out of the following prefixes are required for transforms and transitions and for which browser version? Or could anyone sum it up for me?

Do I need to use all of these for transform?

```
    -webkit-transform: 
    -moz-transform: 
    -ms-transform: 
    -o-transform: 
    transform:
```

And all of these for transition?

```
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
```

Just to be safe?

Comment: please search a little before post any question ... http://caniuse.com/

Comment: I looked at caniuse. Didn't find an actuall explanation. It just says how many % browsers support it unprefixed. Or am I blind?

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm sorry. Is there any stackexchange forum where I could possibly ask this? @Paulie_D

Comment: That's what you get frome caniuse, based on you support needs you can know which prefixes needs to be used

Comment: To me that seems like I can just do transform and -webkit-transform as it doesnt list any other prefixes. Is that the case @DaniP

Comment: That's all you need to do ... check your min support and evaluate what prefixe is need

Comment: I'd suggest you look into [**autoprefixer**](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) it takes all the hard work our of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staying up-to-date with prefixing is a never-ending endeavor that one might want to commit to or, like me, abandon for the sake of better/easier solutions.

Personally, I am from the hard-core purists who put quality of code over functionality. I therefore don't prefix anything.

I know that this is something that is not acceptable for many cases where things need to work on as many machines as possible - for example when you work on client projects - and started to use CSS pre-processors that automatically prefix your CSS code to support a specified set of machines (for example "last 5 versions of all major browsers", or "90% market share"). This way, your code stays clean and you still have a neatly prefixed production-file. Pre-Processors can also do many other handy things; nesting CSS and variables is only two of those things.

To also give a real answer to your question: [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/) is a good service for seeing browser-support on a given CSS property. It also tells you which browser still needs prefixing for a property.

Comment: Thank you. But let's say I put 'translateX' to caniuse it just points me to 2D animations. And says -webkit- si needed on old android browser. So does that mean I can only do -webkit-transofrm and transform in that case?

Comment: I would come to that conclusion, yes. Pressing "show all" also gives you a list of outdated browsers and you see that a lot of them need prefixes. You should also check them before deciding which prefixes to use.

Comment: I really am blind. I never noticed the show all button. That's exactly what I need. FML. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. You would likely need to do your own browser testing for this. [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#home) is probably the most up to date info on supported [transforms](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and [transitions](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition). To be safe I would just use them all. If you are using SASS or LESS you could create a mixin to make your life easier.

LESS

```
.transition (@transition) {
    -webkit-transition: @transition;  
    -moz-transition:    @transition;
    -ms-transition:     @transition; 
    -o-transition:      @transition;
    transition:         @transition;
}
.transform(@transform){
    -webkit-transform:   @transform;
    -moz-transform:      @transform;
    -ms-transform:       @transform;
    -o-transform:        @transform;
    transform:           @transform;
}
```

SASS

```
@mixin transition($transition...) {
    -moz-transition:    $transition;
    -o-transition:      $transition;
    -webkit-transition: $transition;
    transition:         $transition;
}

@mixin transform($transform) {
    -moz-transform:    $transform;
    -o-transform:      $transform;
    -ms-transform:     $transform;
    -webkit-transform: $transform;
    transform:         $transform;
}
```